# How to know when the user deletes the cookies from our website manually?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to have in the frontend a handler to run wheneaver the user deletes the cookies from our website?

This is because I'm building a Single-Page Application (SPA) and want to reduce HTTP requests at max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. All you can do is check to see if the cookie exists. There is no mutation event for a cookie.

Consider local storage as an alternative (these too can be manually deleted though).